# Errno 22 invaild (wb) or filename. Python shutil.copy

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I'm beginner in python and I have a problem with this script:

```
import errno import shutil import os  
        def copystuff(src, dest):
        if os.path.isfile(src):
            dest_dirname = os.path.dirname(src)
            if not os.path.isdir(dest_dirname):
                os.makedirs(dest_dirname)
            shutil.copy2(src, dest)
        else:
            shutil.copytree(src, dest)       
    copystuff('C:\\Downloads\\index.html', 'J:\\include\\')
```

Where J it's `FlashDriveUSB`, and I'm using `Python 2.7`.

When I'm launching this I got something like that:

```
C:\Python27>python copy_file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy_file.py", line 24, in <module>
    copystuff('C:\\Downloads\index.html', 'D:\\include\\')
  File "copy_file.py", line 20, in copystuff
    shutil.copy2(src, dest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 127, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'D:\\include\\'
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem. I wanted copy file to folder witch doesn't exist so i added to code a few lines checking if inputted path exists and if not path is created.